# Pandas: row operations on a column, given one reference value on a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a database that looks like the below. For each fruit (just apple and pears below, for conciseness), we have:
1. yearly sales, 
2. current sales, 
3. monthly sales and 
4.the standard deviation of sales. 
Their ordering may vary, but it's always 4 values per fruit.

```
dataset = {'apple_yearly_avg': [57],
           'apple_sales': [100],
           'apple_monthly_avg':[80],
           'apple_st_dev': [12],
           'pears_monthly_avg': [33],
           'pears_yearly_avg': [35],
           'pears_sales': [40],
           'pears_st_dev':[8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset).T#tranpose 
df = df.reset_index()#clear index
df.columns = (['Description', 'Value'])#name 2 columns
```

I would like to perform two sets of operations.

For the first set of operations, we isolate a fruit price, say 'pears', and subtract each average sales from current sales.

```
 df_pear = df[df.loc[:, 'Description'].str.contains('pear')]
 df_pear['temp'] = df_pear['Value'].where(df_pear.Description.str.contains('sales')).bfill()  
 df_pear ['some_op'] = df_pear['Value'] - df_pear['temp']
```

The above works, by creating a temporary column holding pear_sales of 40, backfill it and then use it to subtract values.
Question 1: is there a cleaner way to perform this operation without a temporary array? Also I do get the common warning saying I should use '.loc[row_indexer, col_indexer], even though the output still works.

For the second sets of operations, I need to add '5' rows equal to 'new_purchases' to the bottom of the dataframe, and then fill df_pear['some_op'] with sales * (1 + std_dev *some_multiplier).

```
df_pear['temp2'] = df_pear['Value'].where(df_pear['Description'].str.contains('st_dev')).bfill()
new_purchases = 5
for i in range(new_purchases):
    df_pear = df_pear.append(df_pear.iloc[-1])#appends 5 copies of the last row

counter = 1
for i in range(len(df_pear)-1, len(df_pear)-new_purchases, -1):#backward loop from the bottom
    df_pear.some_op.iloc[i] = df_pear['temp'].iloc[0] * (1 + df_pear['temp2'].iloc[i] * counter)
    counter += 1
```

[image]
This 'backwards' loop achieves it, but again, I'm worried about readability since there's another temporary column created, and then the indexing is rather ugly?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't 'pairs_montly_avg' a mistake for 'pairs_yearly_avg'?

Comment: Please show the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is a cleaner way to perform your both tasks, for each
fruit in one go:

1. Add 2 columns, *Fruit* and *Descr*, the result of splitting of *Description* at the first "_":

   ```
   df[['Fruit', 'Descr']] = df['Description'].str.split('_', n=1, expand=True)
   ```

   To see the result you may print *df* now.
2. Define the following function to "reformat" the current group:

   ```
   def reformat(grp):
       wrk = grp.set_index('Descr')
       sal = wrk.at['sales', 'Value']
       dev = wrk.at['st_dev', 'Value']
       avg = wrk.at['yearly_avg', 'Value']
       # Subtract (yearly) average
       wrk['some_op'] = wrk.Value - avg
       # New rows
       wrk2 = pd.DataFrame([wrk.loc['st_dev']] * 5).assign(
           some_op=[ sal * (1 + dev * i) for i in range(5, 0, -1) ])
       return pd.concat([wrk, wrk2])  # Old and new rows
   ```
3. Apply this function to each group, grouped by *Fruit*, drop *Fruit*
   column  and save the result back in *df*:

   ```
   df = df.groupby('Fruit').apply(reformat)\
       .reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns='Fruit')
   ```

Now, when you `print(df)`, the result is:

```
          Description  Value  some_op
0    apple_yearly_avg     57        0
1         apple_sales    100       43
2   apple_monthly_avg     80       23
3        apple_st_dev     12      -45
4        apple_st_dev     12     6100
5        apple_st_dev     12     4900
6        apple_st_dev     12     3700
7        apple_st_dev     12     2500
8        apple_st_dev     12     1300
9   pears_monthly_avg     33       -2
10        pears_sales     40        5
11   pears_yearly_avg     35        0
12       pears_st_dev      8      -27
13       pears_st_dev      8     1640
14       pears_st_dev      8     1320
15       pears_st_dev      8     1000
16       pears_st_dev      8      680
17       pears_st_dev      8      360
```

## Edit

I'm in doubt whether *Description* should also be replicated to new
rows from "st_dev" row. If you want some other content there, set it
in *reformat* function, after *wrk2* is created.

Comment: I changed my initial solution to include both your tasks.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just changed wrk['some_op'] = wrk.Value - sal instead of wrk.Value - avg as had pasted wrong image. And thus applying df.at['sales', 'Value'] removes the need of creating the temporary 'sales' column.